# How to get elements from a list inside a while and outside

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, while-loop

At last line i am trying to get the names of the childrens

```
            Console.WriteLine("How many children do you have?");
            int X = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            List<string> nameOfChild = new List<string>();
            int i = 1;
            while(i <= X)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What is the name of your {0} child?", i);
                nameOfChild.Add(Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine()));
                i++;
                **Console.WriteLine("The name of your i child is {0} and was born in the year of {1}.", nameOfChild[i]);**
            }
```

Comment: Change it to `nameOfChild[i - 2]`. The index of the first element is `0`. You start `i` at `1` so it's already 1 ahead and then you also increase it by 1 before you write the name so it'll be 2 ahead everytime you write a name hence the `i - 2`

Answer (score 0):

Indexed collections and arrays start at index 0, not 1. Also, you are incrementing the `i` variable before printing the name.

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("How many children do you have?");
int X = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
List<string> nameOfChild = new List<string>();
int i = 0;
while(i < X)
{
   Console.WriteLine("What is the name of your {0} child?", i + 1);
   nameOfChild.Add(Console.ReadLine());
   Console.WriteLine("The name of your {0} child is {1}.", i + 1, nameOfChild[i]);
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a while loop for something already determined. Same goes for using a List instead of an array. If your teacher insisted on using a List than by all means use it.

For future reference, use variable names that reflect their purpose in the program. Try childList instead of nameOfChild where the name of the child would be an element of the list.

```
Console.WriteLine("How many children do you have?");
int X = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string[] nameOfChild = new string[X];
for (int i = 1; i <= X; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine("What is the name of your {0} child?", i);
     nameOfChild[i - 1] = Console.ReadLine();
     Console.WriteLine("The name of your {0} child is {1} and was born in the year of (insert year).",i, nameOfChild[i - 1]);
}
```

Also your string formatting is missing a year, so I added that in case you forget.